# how to stop the timer in android

Tags: android, timer, uiimageview

This is my code following,I am changing some iamges dynamically in my image view.
    public class LoadingScreen extends Activity{

```
public static Integer[] imageList={R.drawable.food_pics1,R.drawable.food_pics2,R.drawable.food_pics3,
    R.drawable.food_pics4,R.drawable.food_pics5,R.drawable.food_pics6,R.drawable.food_pics7,
    R.drawable.food_pics8,R.drawable.food_pics9};
Thread thread;
ImageView foodImageView;
final Handler myHandler=new Handler();
public int currentImageIndex=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.load_xml);
    foodImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_food);
    //      final int i=0;

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animateImages();
        }


    };

    final int delay=500;            
    final long period=1000;
    Timer timer=new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myHandler.post(runnable);
        }
    }, delay, period);
}

private void animateImages() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        foodImageView.setImageResource(imageList[currentImageIndex%imageList.length]);
        currentImageIndex++;
        foodImageView.getAnimation();
}
```

I want to stop the timer and finish this activity after 20 secs.how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this,

```
 View v = new View(this);
        v.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //cancel your animation and finish the Activity here.
                finish();
            }
         }, (long) 20000.0);
```

Comment: Ur r a saver,U already save my life once nd again u jxt did.thnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can say something like this :

```
timer.cancel();
timer = null;
```

Comment: I know that but where should I use this and also calculate the time for 20 sec.

Comment: plz tell me where shuld I use it and calculate 20 secs.

Comment: AFAIK, after elapsing 20 seconds, you call the above method.You can just start a another thread and a counter. increment that counter after every 1 sec. if that counter becomes 20 seconds,then call  timer.cancel().Hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

Save the TimerTask instance in the class and invoke [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29) on it.

Here's a tip I found very useful **without** using Java's Timer: Try synchronizing things in the UI thread, especially if you want to do UI tasks. Example:

```
... onCreate() {
getUiThreadHandler().post(new Runnable(){
  if (canceled()) {
    return;
  }

  // Actual work
  ...

  // Invoke again after delay
  getUiThreadHandler().postDelayed(this, 500);
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Regarding the delay, it's a parameter in the postDelayed() method.

Comment: Regarding the overall time, the isCanceleted() method should check this.

Comment: BTW, if you want a different delay time and period time, you can play with the first post() vs. the inner second postDelayed().